# Jenkins can't see Maven install

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

All of this is on one machine. I've got Maven installed. I can run mvn and the expected maven stuff happens. When configuring Jenkins I set the path for the setting.xml as the absolute path. However, in my project configuration jenkins tells me "Jenkins needs to know where your Maven is installed. Please do so from the tool configuration." I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Jenkins Global Tool Configuration u can install maven and use it in your jobs.
2. If you want to use system installed maven check which "user" Jenkins is working on and install it in /home/user/.m2/ directory. To check if everything is set correctly run these commands.

   ```
    sudo su username 
    mvn -v
   ```

Comment: Ok I figured what was wrong. There was the maven section lower down in the tools menu that I hadn't done. The instructions I was given weren't very clear about setting it up I guess.